# Как удалить контакт в AMOCRM ajax запросом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Хочу удалить контакт ajax запросом. Вот что у меня получилось но не работает можете подсказать что не так?

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/contacts/detail/'+$id+'',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'ACTION': "DELETE", 'ID' : $id} ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                  console.log(response.status);

                },
                error: function () {
                  console.log("error");
                }
              });
```

Comment: Каким API вы пользуетесь? Где его документация? Все, что удалось найти - вот https://www.amocrm.ru/developers/content/crm_platform/contacts-api, но тут как будто контакты вообще не предусмотрено удалять. Вам бы лучше в поддержку сервиса (вы же деньги за это платите?), а не сюда.